# How to shuffle list whenever click is triggered

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-flow

I have Json Data through which I'm doing this .

```
 fun getFact(context: Context) = viewModelScope.launch{
    try {
        val format = Json {
            ignoreUnknownKeys = true
            prettyPrint = true
            isLenient = true
        }

        val factJson = context.assets.open("Facts.json").bufferedReader().use {
            it.readText()
        }
        val factList = format.decodeFromString<List<FootballFact>>(factJson)
        _uiState.value = ViewState.Success(factList)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
        _uiState.value = ViewState.Error(exception = e)
    }
}
```

This is the way i m getting my job from viewModle in Ui sceeen

```
    viewModel.getFact(context)  


when (val result = 
viewModel.uiState.collectAsState().value) {
        is ViewState.Error -> {
            Toast.makeText(
                context,
                "Error ${result.exception}",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }

        is ViewState.Success -> {
            val factsLists = mutableStateOf(result.fact)
            val randomFact = factsLists.value[0]

            FactCard(quote = randomFact.toString()) {
                factsLists.value.shuffled()
            }

        }
    }
```

I have fact card where i want to show that fact .also i have there a lambda for click where i want my factList to refresh every time whenever is clicked.

```
@Composable
fun FactCard(quote: String , onClick : ()-> Unit) {
    
   val fact = remember { mutableStateOf(quote)}
    
   Box(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        modifier = Modifier.
                .clickable { onClick() }
        ) {
    
           Text(.. )
       }
}
```

I don't know how to approach this, i think there is silly thing I'm doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Composables can only recompose when you update state data. You aren't doing that. Your click event should return the new quote that you want to display. You then set `fact.value` to the new quote. Calling `fact.value` with a new value is what triggers a recompose:

```
when (val result = viewModel.uiState.collectAsState().value) {
    is ViewState.Error -> {
         Toast.makeText(
              context,
              "Error ${result.exception}",
              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
         ).show()
    }

    is ViewState.Success -> {
         val factsLists = mutableStateOf(result.fact)
         val randomFact = factsLists.value[0]

         FactCard(quote = randomFact.toString()) {
              return factsLists.value.shuffled()[0]
         }

    }
}

@Composable
fun FactCard(quote: String , onClick : ()-> String) {
  
 var fact = remember { mutableStateOf(quote)}
  
 Box(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        modifier = Modifier.
                  .clickable { 
                  fact.value = onClick() 
            }
        ) {
  
            Text(.. )
      }
}
```

Comment: for sure i getting the randome value for the first time but i want wenever i click there there is agian shuffle in list . please go through my issue .

Comment: @AshishGautam I updated my response.

Comment: thanks for giving direction.

Answer (score 3):

`factsLists.shuffled()` returns a new list with the elements of this list randomly shuffled.

Comment: i have used this but while on clicking shuffle method is not trigging .

Comment: Be aware of list.shuffle() and list.shuffled(), this is not the same function. list.shuffle randomly shuffles elements in  list while list.shuffled() returns a new list with the elements of this list randomly shuffled.